# In Java, how do you obtain a Socket or DatagramSocket from the file descriptor of an already opened C socket?

Tags: java, c, sockets, tcp, udp

I have a Linux program split into two parts.

One part does NAT traversal to obtain either a UDP socket (UDP hole punching) or a TCP socket (TCP hole punching). Part one is written in C to allow for native features which facilitate or enhance the NAT traversal process. Part two actually uses the connected socket obtained via the NAT traversal performed in part one.

Now here is the problem. I want the first part, the part that obtains the socket, to be independent of the second part, the part that uses the socket for an application specific purpose. For example, I want the first part to be reusable for a variety of different applications that all need UDP and TCP connections that were established between peers.

Right now, I would like the second part (the application part) to be written in Java rather than C or C++. I want the second part to use a socket connection that was obtained by the C code responsible for NAT traversal. Let's say the first part established a connection and then returns a struct:

```
// Represents a TCP or UDP connection that was obtained in part one.
struct ConnectionObtained {
    int socket_file_descriptor;
    int source_port;
    int destination_port;
    int source_address; // 4 byte ipv4 address
    int destination_address;
    int is_UDP; // 1 for UDP client socket, 0 for TCP client socket 
};
```

The C code in part one can provide this POD/struct to the Java code in part two either via JNI (Java Native Interface) or via inter-proceess communication.

I want the Java code to use that information to construct an object whose declared type is either java.net.DatagramSocket or java.net.Socket and then use that object wherever a DatagramSocket or Socket would be expected.

As a starting point, consider the following sample code...

```
/** 
 * Determines the Unix file descriptor number of the given  {@link ServerSocket}.
 */
private int getUnixFileDescriptor(ServerSocket ss) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {
  Field $impl=ss.getClass().getDeclaredField("impl");
  $impl.setAccessible(true);
  SocketImpl socketImpl=(SocketImpl)$impl.get(ss);
  Method $getFileDescriptor=SocketImpl.class.getDeclaredMethod("getFileDescriptor");
  $getFileDescriptor.setAccessible(true);
  FileDescriptor fd=(FileDescriptor)$getFileDescriptor.invoke(socketImpl);
  Field $fd=fd.getClass().getDeclaredField("fd");
  $fd.setAccessible(true);
  return (Integer)$fd.get(fd);
}
```

The code makes it appear that it may be possible to "recreates a bound  {@link ServerSocket} on the given file descriptor." Does this mean that it is possible to "recreates a bound  {@link java.net.Socket} on the given file descriptor" as well? What about a bound {@link java.net.DatagramSocket}?

```
/** 
 * Recreates a bound  {@link ServerSocket} on the given file descriptor.
 */
private ServerSocket recreateServerSocket(int fdn) throws Exception {
  FileDescriptor fd=new FileDescriptor();
  Field $fd=FileDescriptor.class.getDeclaredField("fd");
  $fd.setAccessible(true);
  $fd.set(fd,fdn);
  Class $PlainSocketImpl=Class.forName("java.net.PlainSocketImpl");
  Constructor $init=$PlainSocketImpl.getDeclaredConstructor(FileDescriptor.class);
  $init.setAccessible(true);
  SocketImpl socketImpl=(SocketImpl)$init.newInstance(fd);
  ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket();
  ss.bind(new InetSocketAddress(0));
  Field $impl=ServerSocket.class.getDeclaredField("impl");
  $impl.setAccessible(true);
  $impl.set(ss,socketImpl);
  return ss;
}
```

Comment: If the Java code only needs to be concerned with connected sockets, why is your Java code full of tricks on the `ServerSocket?`

Comment: If I understood correctly, do you want to use an existing opened socket as the underlying socket of a new Java client Socket ?

Comment: Possible dupe:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243546/can-i-get-a-java-socket-from-a-file-descriptor-number

Comment: @perencie - yes. If I want to use an existing opened C socket as the underlying socket of a new Java client Socket?

Comment: @EJP - because these were the only examples I could find of getting and creating Java sockets from file descriptors. I thought it might be possible to change "recreateServerSocket(int fdn)" to "recreateUDPSocket(int fdn)" or "recreateClientSocket(int fdn)" and then use that code to make the UDP or TCP socket from the C file descriptor of an already opened C socket.

Comment: @AndrewHenie - But my Java libraries don't use FileOutputStream or FileInputStream. They expect an instance of class java.net.DatagramSocket or class java.net.Socket to be passed to them in the form of method parameters so they can use these instances to send and receive data.

Comment: @AndrewHernie - Would you perhaps recommend subclassing java.net.DatagramSocket and java.net.Socket and then having the user-defined subclasses take in a FileOutputStream and a FileInputStream in their constructors? Their send and receive calls could forward to the streams so that the libraries think that they are using a DatagramSocket or a Socket.

Comment: You've fundamentally got the right idea (hacking into `impl.fd`), but for an already-open and connected file descriptor, this gets _very complicated, very fast_. The reason is that `Socket`, `SocketImpl->AbstractPlainSocketImpl->PlainSocketImpl->SocksSocketImpl`, `Inet*Address`, `FileDescriptor` and on have a vast amount of state (e.g. `boolean created = false, shut_wr = false;`), and you'd need to punch in the right values for all of the state of a socket. Here's `PlainSocketImpl`: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/814bf0775b52/src/solaris/native/java/net/PlainSocketImpl.c#l245

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist - That sounds like too much effort for me. I would rather just do the native part in C++, make a C++ class that resembles Java Socket and then create a Java class that forwards its methods to the C++ class. The C++ class would provide methods like "close" and "read" and "write" and the Java class would just forward to it. I could make the Java class extend Socket so any libraries that see this class would think that it is a Socket. My only concern is that it might not behave the same which might cause bugs/problems, but I think it would be a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transfer file descriptor between processes (at least on POSIX systems) accroding [Can I share a file descriptor to another process on linux or are they local to the process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358684/can-i-share-a-file-descriptor-to-another-process-on-linux-or-are-they-local-to-t)

Also as mentioned in comments (thanks to @Andrew Henle) you can hack Java through reflection and create IO streams for existing file descriptor: [Can I get a Java Socket from a file descriptor number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243546/can-i-get-a-java-socket-from-a-file-descriptor-number) Also it is possible extend Socket class and override getInputStream/getOutputStream methods.

But actually I suggest you use first part as proxy. Java part just opens server socket on localhost and then C++ part retransmits traffic between localhost and WAN address.

Comment: "But actually I suggest you use first part as proxy". That last sentence was grammatically incorrect. After you bind the TCP server socket with Java and pass the native socket to C++, how will you get the resulting client socket back to Java?

Comment: You should not transfer socket, you should transfer traffic: Client <---> C++ server <---> Java server (<---> - socket connection)

Answer (score 4):

You're asking two different questions. Can you pass a bound socket from C code written in a separate process and can you pass a bound socket from C code written in the same process.

For the first part, no, it's not possible if the C code is in one application and the Java code is another because if it were possible, than multiple different applications would be able to pass around a socket (without SCM_RIGHTS). Killing the application that created and bound the socket initially would create problems for the other applications using/sharing that socket.

As for having the C code be in the native part of a Java application (i.e. via jni), in that case the operating system wouldn't be able to differentiate whether the socket is in the Java part of the user code or the C part, so you don't run into the problem introduced in the previous paragraph. It is possible to pass a socket (file descriptor int and native socket descriptor) between Java and native code (see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207881/using-a-java-socket-from-jni-c-code)), but that doesn't tell you if it would be practical in this scenario.

As for making a java.net.Socket or a java.net.DatagramSocket from a bound socket file descriptor that came from jni code, I have no idea. You would have to try it yourself.

Comment: You don't have to answer to your question as if you are 3rd person. Might be wrongly interpreted as DID or somewhat programmer schizophrenia. And it quite confused me on a first view I must admit.

Comment: Hahaha. I actually talk to myself regularly, lol. But seriously, I thought that someone would be more likely to post a (good/complete/functional) answer if there was already a bad/incomplete/non-functional one there.