# transfer C++ socket handle to Java on windows

Tags: java, c++, windows

I got a socket handle in C++; then it spawned off a child Java program.

I used the following code and able to open up the streams in my Java program on Linux.

[Can I get a Java Socket from a file descriptor number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243546/can-i-get-a-java-socket-from-a-file-descriptor-number)

But the same code does not work on Windows.

I have been researching it for a couple weeks but not able to find any solution.

Does anyone know how to do it if possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are TCP SOCKET handles inheritable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847793/are-tcp-socket-handles-inheritable)